# Sending an SNS Notification when Alarm state changes to OK From "ALARM " state but not from "INSUFFICIENT_DATA"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I made changes that I should get SNS notification (Email) when My alarm goes to ALARM --> OK and OK --> ALARM state.. but it's triggering also when ALarm goes to OK state from INSUFFICIENT_DATA.

I don't want a notification in second condition (INSUFFICIENT_DATA-->OK)

currently my template.yaml code says:

```
OKActions: 
        - !Ref AlarmSNSTopic
  AlarmSNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
```

what changes I need to make?